# Paste data starting in column P of google sheets (via script)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to post an array into column P daily. Because it's posting daily, I'd like it to also grab the last row.

I'm pulling from another workbook but don't know how to get the paste to work.

```
Function () {
  var toCopy = [copies data from spreadsheet 1]
  /* trying to paste into Aggregate tab in spreadsheet 2*/
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById(‘spreadsheet 2’);
  var tsh2=ss2.getSheetByName('Aggregate');
  var tsh2.getLastRow(???
}
```

How do I paste var toCopy into column P? The array is 15 columns wide.

Comment: Which is the array of `toCopy` 1 dimensional array or 2 dimensional array?

Comment: 2 dimensional array: 15 columns wide and around 600 rows tall (but shrinking daily)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about the array of `toCopy`. In your goal, you want to put the values of `toCopy` which has the 600 rows and 15 columns from the next row of the last of column "P" in the sheet of `Aggregate`. And the numbers of rows and columns of `toCopy` are changed every run of the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I want to put the toCopy values in columns P-AD daily. You're correct re rows - the count changes every run but the columns are fixed at 15.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that you want to put `toCopy` to the columns "P" to "AD", while the number of rows is changed. In this case, do you want to append the values to the last row of columns "P" to "AD"? Or do you want to put the values to the columns "P" to "AD" after it clears the range of the columns "P" to "AD"?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying some of these points I might have omitted.. I'd like to append the values to the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your goal. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to append the values to the next row of the last row of column "P" in the sheet of "Aggregate".
- The values are 2 dimensional array which has 600 rows and 15 columns.

  - The number of rows is changed every run.
  - The number of columns is not changed.
- After the values are put, you want to retrieve the last row number.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve the last row number of the column "P".

   - From your question, I'm not sure whether the last row of the column "P" is the last row of the sheet. So the last row is checked for only column "P".
2. Append "toCopy" to the next row of the last row of column "P".
3. Retrieve the current last row number.

#### Modified script:

Please set the values of `toCopy` and the Spreadsheet ID.

```
function myFunction() {
  var toCopy = [copies data from spreadsheet 1]

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Aggregate');

  // Retrieve the last row of the column "P".
  var lastRowOfColP = 0;
  var valuesOfColP = sheet.getRange("P1:P").getValues();
  for (var i = valuesOfColP.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (valuesOfColP[i][0]) {
      lastRowOfColP = i + 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Put "toCopy" to the next row of the last row of column "P".
  sheet.getRange(lastRowOfColP + 1, 16, toCopy.length, toCopy[0].length).setValues(toCopy);

  // Retrieve the current last row number.
  var currentLastRow = lastRowOfColP + toCopy.length;
  Logger.log(currentLastRow)
}
```

- This modified script supposes that `toCopy` is 2 dimensional array.

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: You've done it! Thanks so much my friend. You are a life saver!!

Comment: @econobro Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Set a range's values](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/spreadsheetapp#set-a-ranges-values) is what you're after.

```
function () {
  var values = [
    // Copied data from spreadsheet 1
  ]

  // Paste into Aggregate tab in spreadsheet 2
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(‘spreadsheet 2’);
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName('Aggregate');

  var range = sheet2.getRange('P1:P15');
  range.setValues(values);

  // Grab last row
  var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow();
}
```

PS: Watch out for the formatting in your code. It looks like you might not be using a proper [text editor](https://github.com/collections/text-editors). Your formatting made `function` be `Function` and the quotations  `'spreadsheet 2'` become `‘spreadsheet 2’`. I use VS Code and Vim, for example.

Comment: I typed the 'Function' portion in notes so it capitalized when it shouldn't have, but thanks for pointing out. Unfortunately, this script doesn't integrate with my code. My values are defined in var toCopy and resetting them in range breaks the script. Also, I think your range of 'P1:P15' would be rows. I'm looking to post this in column P which is the 15th column over. Any ideas?